# Regex to detect cuits - Python

Tags: regex, numbers

I need to find a regex that allows me to identify the following sequence. Two numbers space 8 numbers space one number. Between the numbers can appear multiple combinations of characters.

```
\d{2}.?\d{8}.?\d{1}
```

Should match:

```
11 11111111 1
11-11111111-1
11.11111111.1
11|11111111|1
11.11111111  1
11  11111111  1
```

Should not match:

```
11  11111111  11
1  11111111  11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```js
(?<!\d)\d{2}\D*\d{8}\D*\d(?!\d)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/A15LGM/3).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{8}                    digits (0-9) (8 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: The problem is that this combination 111111111111111111111111111111111111 also matches.

Comment: @Raymont Nowhere in this world, see https://regex101.com/r/A15LGM/2. My expression matches strings with 11 digits max.

Comment: The point is that this numerical expression could be anywhere in the string, not necessarily at the beginning or at the end.

Comment: @Raymont I have changed the solution, please have a look.